# retrieve data from pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have gone through some similar topics but did not find the working solution. Mostly I did not understand the concept well.
I have a simple database with the following structure:

```
QUESTIONS
qid
question

TAGS
tagid
tag name

QUESTION_TAGS
qid
tagid
```

My Question model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $table="questions";

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question_tags','qid','qid');
    }

}
```

my Tags model:

```
class Tags extends Model
{
    protected $table="tags";
}
```

Question_tags model:

```
class Question_tags extends Model
{
    protected $table="question_tags";
}
```

Question controller:

```
class QuestionCtrl extends Controller
{

    public function getquesdet(){
        $id = Request::input('id');

        $question = Question::where('q_id','=',$id)->with('tags')
        ->get();

        return $question;      
  }
 };
```

as expected, the returned value consists of `ids`. so, I want the returned value to be the `tag names`. I would be happy to hear some explanation.

Comment: I am also facing such a problem. I need all question according to the tag_id from tag model. please let me know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking your DB schemas it's a [`many-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation so your relationship function should be as:

In `Question` model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this-> belongsToMany('App\Tags', 'QUESTION_TAGS', 'qid', 'tagid');
}
```

In `Tags` model:

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this-> belongsToMany('App\Question', 'QUESTION_TAGS', 'tagid', 'qid');
}
```

Then in your controller, you can write as:

```
$question = Question::where('q_id','=',$id)->with('tags')->first();

return $question->tags->pluck('name'); // returns array of tag names
```

*Note - There is no need to define a model for pivot table `Question_tags`.*

Comment: I am getting this error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tags.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `tags`.*, `Question_tags`.`q_id` as `pivot_q_id`, `Question_tags`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id` from `tags` inner join `Question_tags` on `tags`.`id` = `Question_tags`.`tag_id` where `Question_tags`.`q_id` in ())`

Comment: I did not use any column named id

Comment: I am assuming `tagid` is the Primary Key for the table `TAGS` so set this `protected $primaryKey = 'tagid';` in your `tags` model and try the query again. And also same goes for `QUESTIONS` model.

Comment: that worked!thanks a lot. Why should i add the $primarykey?

Comment: Because Laravel assumes you have a `primarykey` named as `id` but in your case, it was not true so you have to override it.

Comment: so I assume that every table has to be overridden if there's a different primary key

Comment: Yes, you have to override it for a different primary key. And I also recommend you to use the convention for columns names and table names as `id` for PK, plural table name and singular model name.

Answer (score 1):

hello in you example you are trying to make a many to many relation between questions and tags and your database looks good.
but in your models you have made relational function to populate related data the problem in that functions.
your question model is

```
class Question extends Model
{
protected $table="questions";

public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question_tags','qid','qid');
}

}
```

in this you are using `hasMany` function that is used to make the relation of 1 to many.

Use the function `belongsToMany` to make the relation many to many.